# RabbitMq: Lazy queues and ttl

Tags: rabbitmq

Does the feature of a rabbitMq queue with a time-to-live work with lazy queues? 
From what I can see, a lazy queue is no different than a standard queue when it comes to ttl. 
Reading this in the documentation makes me think it won't work.

> Lazy Queues - queues that move their contents to disk as early as practically possible, and only load them in RAM when requested by consumers

https://www.rabbitmq.com/lazy-queues.html
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

Comment: Did you try it out yourself?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. My bad, I should have updated this